# Problems with #pragma once

Tags: c++, c, gcc

`#pragma once` is not working properly when compiling a project I have been working on.  Having read up on the topic a bit, I saw that the one downside to using it is that if the same file is in different locations then it will not work like the other way of using include guards like so:

```
#ifndef __SOMETHING_H__ 
#define __SOMETHING_H__
```

Here is the error:

```
../../engine/scene/../common/../bitsquid/queue.h:78:29: error: redefinition of    ‘template<class T> void foundation::queue::reserve(foundation::Queue<T>&, uint32_t)’
../../engine/scene/../common/../bitsquid/queue.h:78:29: error: ‘template<class T> void foundation::queue::reserve(foundation::Queue<T>&, uint32_t)’ previously declared here
```

You can see that the path is the same.  I am using g++ to compile the source.  I would usually just replace this with the other style of include guards but I would like to avoid that as I did not write the library.

gcc version is 4.6.3

Comment: That's a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: http://sscce.org TESTCASE!

Comment: do you have the same guarded file in multiple locations? I only see one location.

Comment: You can confirm whether the problem is really with  `#pragma once` by replacing it with include guards and observing if that resolves your error.

Comment: @chris by "that" I assume you mean `__SOMETHING_H__`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the definition of `#pragma once` is that *the current file* is only included once.

If you copy it somewhere else, then the file is different, which means that it's considered different from the `#pragma once` perspective.

If you want to copy the file somewhere else and get a similar behaviour to `#pragma once`, then you need to use include guards.

> also you shouldn't be using `__HEADER_H__` for the include guard, the use of a leading `__` is reserved and can lead to subtle bugs.

Additionally, having looked at the [code on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/bitsquid/foundation/src/7f896236dbafd2cb842655004b1c7bf6e76dcef9/queue.h?at=default), the file `queue.h` has neither an `#include` guard, nor has it a `#pragma once` guard, which indicates a false premise in this case.

If you're trying to munge a bunch of .cpp files into a single one, and they are `#include`ing the same file in this case then you'll get this exact error.

Comment: That was the problem, queue.h had neither an include guard or the \#pragma once.  Good eye!